# How to move a file into a subdirectory with bash?

Tags: bash, directory, subdirectory, mv

so I'm having trouble with moving my file into a subdirectory. Right now I have a jpg file in my Downloads folder that I want to move over to my images folder, which is contained inside my Desktop and odin-links-and-images folders. Just for a bit of clarification, my Downloads folder is a completely separate directory, and I want to move the jpg file inside my Downloads folder to
Desktop/odin-links-and-images/images

What I've tried so far is doing the following command inside my Downloads directory:

```
mv dog.jpg images/
```

Doing this, I ended up getting the error:

```
 mv: cannot move 'dog.jpg' to 'images/': Not a directory
```

I assume this is because my dog.jpg file is in my Downloads folder, which is a completely separate directory from my Desktop/odin-links-and-images/images directory. I'm not sure if it's possible to move my jpg file, but I'd appreciate any guidance on how to do this!

Answer (score 2):

Write the complete path to images:

```bash
mv dog.jpg ~/Desktop/odin-links-and-images/images
```

This is assuming Desktop is in home. Otherwise, use whatever is the full path to desktop.

Comment: ... and if you're not currently in your **Downloads** folder, specify the full path to that too `mv ~/Downloads/dog.jpg  -/Desktop/odin-links-and-images/images`